# react-native : horizontal scrollview won't work inside flatlist

Tags: react-native

I have a horizontal scrollview inside my flatlist but it won't scroll.

```
renderRow = ({ item }) => {   
 return (
  <View style={{width:'100%', backgroundColor:'transparent'}}>
 <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
  //I have multiple images here      
 </ScrollView>
 </View>

      )
    }
```

This is my flatlist

```
<FlatList
           keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
           data={this.state.data}
           renderItem={this.renderRow}
         />
```

is it possible to put horizontal scrollview inside flatlist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add style width:100% in ScrollView

```js
<ScrollView horizontal={true} style={{width:'100%'}}>
  //I have multiple images here      
 </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try somethig like this:

```
<ScrollView horizontal={true} style={{flex: 1}}>
  //Place Mutiple image in ScrollView.    
 </ScrollView>
```